# IBM Worklight 5.0.x - Changing the main HTML filename

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I want my main html file to have a different name than my project.

I have found that Worklight will not reconnect if I don't use the same name. I have tried changing the mainFile tag in the application-descriptor.xml and changing the wlMainFile entry in worklight.plist on iOS.

Direct Update does not work. More importantly the application does not reconnect and I get a grey screen (presumably because iOS is trying to launch using the wrong file).

For example:

```
Project name: MyProject
main file: home.html
application-descriptor.xml: <mainFile>home.html</mainFile>
worklight.plist: <wlMainFile>home.html</wlMainFile>
```

The above does not work.

[Edited later to add my application-descriptor.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
             5725-G92 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006, 2012. All Rights Reserved.
         US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
         disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp. -->
<!-- Attribute "id" must be identical to application folder name -->
<application xmlns="http://www.worklight.com/application-descriptor" id="agent" platformVersion="5.0.6">
 <displayName>My app</displayName>
 <description>My application description </description>
 <author>
    <name>Redacted</name>
    <email>redacted@foo.com</email>
    <homepage>http://redacted.com</homepage>
    <copyright>(c) redacted LLC</copyright>
 </author>
<height>748</height>
<width>1024</width>
<mainFile>home.html</mainFile>
<thumbnailImage>common/images/ipad-app-icon.png</thumbnailImage>
<!--  -->
<ipad bundleId="com.redacted.myproject" version="1.0">
    <worklightSettings include="true"/>
    <security>
        <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
    </security>
</ipad>
<!--  -->
<android version="1.0">
    <worklightSettings include="true"/>
    <security>
        <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
        <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        <publicSigningKey>Replace this text with the public key of the certificate with which you sign the APK. 
        For details see the Worklight Developer's Reference Guide.</publicSigningKey>
    </security>
</android>
<worklightServerRootURL>http://${local.IPAddress}:8080</worklightServerRootURL>
</application>
```

So, to be clear, if I have encountered an issue with my mainFile being a name other than the project name. Worklight does not always call the filename specified by mainfile, especially after the initial use of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If changing the HTML filename, make sure to also change:

1. The `application folder` name
2. In application-descriptor.xml:

   - `id` attribute in the `application` element
   - `mainFile` element value

All should match each other.

Make sure to delete the native folder and re-build the project.
Application will continue loading after the first time, and Direct Update will continue to function.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Idan Adar. I thoroughly double-checked. I do not have references to my main HTML file in any of the other files you mentioned (the main CSS file, the main JavaScript file). I DID change the filename in the various places in application-descriptor.xml, the filename itself (obviously), and in worklight.plist (for iOS).

Comment: No point in changing it in worklight.plist, the contents of the file are generated in build time, so need to focus on the other files. What I meant was that you want to change all that I have mentioned to be the same name. Edit your question with your application-descriptor.xml.

Comment: Make sure you are re-building the project after changing the filenames and references. And use the updated generated Xcode project to run on your device.

Comment: Thanks Idan. Yes, I'm certainly rebuilding the project after making the changes.This includes verifying that worklight.plist is updated. The issue is that unless the mainFile is the same as the project, the application does not run reliably.

Comment: Seems I have indeed missed the change APPLICATION FOLDER rename part (not Project folder). Please see my revised answer.

Comment: OK. So, to be clear, if you change the mainFile name you MUST also change the name of the application to match. The project can be a different name but the application and mainFile must match. The generated native directory must be regenerated. Knowing this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found is to name my main file the same name as the application within the project. My application runs fine when I do this.

[Note that this has been edited to match @Idan Adar's recommendation above. It's not the PROJECT that must match the mainFile, but the APPLICATION name]

The following works fine:

```
Project name: MyProject
main file: MyProject.html
application-descriptor.xml: <mainFile>MyProject.html</mainFile>
worklight.plist: <wlMainFile>MyProject.html</wlMainFile> (this is a generated file)
```

It appears that Worklight launches the iOS application properly the first time using the file specified in wlMainFile. Then when it has to resume or restart, it's looking for the application name rather than the value specified in wlMainFile.

Comment: This happens because you did not fully change it where required. See my answer.

Comment: I did fully change the file names in all the places you required. Interestingly, on initial app launch the HTML file mentioned in wlMainFile and the application-descriptor.xml is used. Upon restart of the iOS application the HTML file with the same name as the project is the file that is called. Please consider removing the -1 vote down. At least my answer is A solution.